# What is the difference between `(1)(2)` and `x = 1; (x)(2)` in Julia?

Tags: julia

What is the difference between `(1)(2)` and `x = 1; (x)(2)` as being shown below?

```
julia> (1)(2)
2

# but
julia> x = 1
1
julia> (x)(2)
ERROR: MethodError: objects of type Int64 are not callable
```

Thanks.

Quoted from [here](https://miguelraz.github.io/blog/juliawats/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Juxtaposition of number literals is special cased in Julia's parser, so similar to how `2x` parses as `2 * x`, `(1)(2)` (or equivalently `1(2)`) parses as `1 * 2`. `(x)(2)` on the other hand is just regular function call syntax, just as `x(2)` is. This errors if `x` is a number, because numbers in Julia are not callable.

Answer (score 3):

While Simeon exactly described what happened, note that in similar cases you can always use `dump(quote; ...; end)` to get the information what is going on:

```
julia> dump(quote
       (1)(2)
       end)
Expr
  head: Symbol block
  args: Array{Any}((2,))
    1: LineNumberNode
      line: Int64 2
      file: Symbol REPL[2]
    2: Expr
      head: Symbol call
      args: Array{Any}((3,))
        1: Symbol *
        2: Int64 1
        3: Int64 2

julia> dump(quote
       (x)(2)
       end)
Expr
  head: Symbol block
  args: Array{Any}((2,))
    1: LineNumberNode
      line: Int64 2
      file: Symbol REPL[3]
    2: Expr
      head: Symbol call
      args: Array{Any}((2,))
        1: Symbol x
        2: Int64 2
```

You can see that the first case parses to multiplication and the second to a function call.

Comment: You could just call `Meta.@dump (1)(2)` which also avoids wrapping everything inside a `block` expression